# Python error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression, statsmodels, p-value

With more than 250 independent variables, I am trying to find variables that are statistically significant. For this, I am trying to build a for loop which will only return the variables whose P-value is less than alpha.

```
cols = x2.columns
alpha = 0.05
for i in cols:
    if (est2.pvalues[i] < alpha) == True:
        print(i)
```

where `est2 = sm.OLS(y,x2).fit()`. This is the output that I get:

```
LotArea
OverallQual
OverallCond
YearBuilt
YearRemodAdd
BsmtFinSF1
TotalBsmtSF
1stFlrSF
2ndFlrSF
GrLivArea
BsmtFullBath
HalfBath
GarageArea
WoodDeckSF
EnclosedPorch
ScreenPorch
MSZoning_FV
MSZoning_RH
MSZoning_RL
MSZoning_RM
LotConfig_FR2
LotConfig_Inside
LandSlope_Sev
Neighborhood_Crawfor
Neighborhood_Edwards
Neighborhood_MeadowV
Neighborhood_NridgHt
Neighborhood_StoneBr
Condition1_Norm
Condition1_PosN
Condition2_PosN
Condition2_RRAe
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-192-8387e9b8424a> in <module>
      2 alpha = 0.05
      3 for i in cols:
----> 4     if (est2.pvalues[i] < alpha) == True:
      5         print(i)
      6     #print(i, est2.pvalues[i] > alpha)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1440     @final
   1441     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1442         raise ValueError(
   1443             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1444             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

It stops in the middle like this.

Comment: Your column names are not unique, so that you are ending up with a vector instead of a single variable.  You should ensure column names are all distinct.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `== True` is superfluous, but that shouldn't have anything to do with the error.

The error indicates that for one of the variable names `i` (This is a bit misleading by the way, since `i` would usually be an integer in a loop like this.) the expression `est2.pvalues[i]` is a pandas series, not just a single value. Why exactly that happens is impossible to tell without seeing the problematic variable name.

In any case, `est2.pvalues` is a pandas series, so you can get all the low p-values (and the corresponding variable names) with Boolean indexing like this:

```py
est2.pvalues[est2.pvalues < 0.05]
```